# Setting up memory pagination

Tags: memory-management, x86, operating-system

> Next, the loader creates a basic page table. This page table maps the 64 MB at the base of virtual memory (starting at virtual address
>   0) directly to the identical physical addresses. It also maps the same
>   physical memory starting at virtual address LOADER_PHYS_BASE, which
>   defaults to 0xc0000000 (3 GB). The Pintos kernel only wants the latter
>   mapping, but there's a chicken-and-egg problem if we don't include the
>   former: our current virtual address is roughly 0x20000, the location
>   where the loader put us, and we can't jump to 0xc0020000 until we turn
>   on the page table, but if we turn on the page table without jumping
>   there, then we've just pulled the rug out from under ourselves.

A citation comes from: https://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs140-winter16/pintos/pintos_6.html

I think that I don't understand exactly what does it is written above.
My issues:

1. Let's assume that kernel was loaded at 0x20000 physical address by bootloader. From what I understand two different virtual address are mapped to the same place- to the kernel. The first, direct mapping: `~0x20000 -> ~0x20000`. And the second `~0xc0000000 -> ~0x20000`. But, why there is need to use two mappings?
2. I cannot see why the page table ( and page directory) must be mapped by identity.

Please explain.

Comment: This article is assuming a higher half kernel is being used. The idea is that after paging is enabled the kernel will appear to be mapped to the linear address range starting at 0xc0000000. So first you need a mapping for the pages containing your kernel in low memory (starting at 0x20000) because without those you will not be able to execute your code when paging is first turned on. The reason you also need to map ~0xc0000000 -> ~0x20000 is because you will be using a JMP to continue your kernel in high memory. The JMP will fail if the target memory addr doesn't have proper paging entries.

Comment: So basically to do the JMP from low memory to higher half requires that the place you are jumping from is mapped and executable and the location you are jumping to is mapped and executable.

Comment: As for #2, that was a design choice by those who developed PintOS. It may have been done to make it easier for students to understand. Page Table and Page Directory entries (and the Page Directory itself) use physical addresses but those physical addresses could have been mapped and used via higher half addressing as well. Having them 1:1 is not a requirement for an OS.